# Why we use arraylist to store java bean in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, javabeans

in jsp why we use arraylist to store javabean and what happens without using arraylist to use javabean in jsp during jdbc connectivity. in many source codes i have seen that javabean is stored in arraylist and then accessed in jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many cases one does not make direct JDBC calls from within JSPs/Servlets and such. It depends on the architecture of an application.

E.g. if a JSP or Servlet accesses the database through an EJB, the database session gets lost when returning from the EJB call (because it's bound to a transaction), thus making it necessary to buffer values (most likely beans) in some kind of collection. An `ArrayList` provides very fast random access and is also very compact (because it's backed by an array), so it's a natural choice of most programmers.